# ERROR: swupdate-2021.04-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed | json-c/json.h: No such file or directory

Tags: libcurl, libconfig, swupdate

I am trying to integrate SWUpdate framework with Hawkbit. I am facing some issue after changing configuration to include Suricatta in SWUpdate. Steps I have done:

1. Enabled Suricatta in menuconfig.
2. Ran `make` command. No issues here
3. Bitbaked again the image recipe which includes swupdate-image.inc which installs swupdate package. Now I am getting below errors:

swupdate-image.inc is included in meta-swupdate and it includes `swupdate, swupdate-client, swupdate-progress, and swupdate-tools-hawkbit`

ERROR: swupdate-2021.04-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: swupdate-2021.04-r0 do_compile: Execution of '[....]/swupdate/2021.04-r0/temp/run.do_compile.18762' failed with exit code 1

It mainly complains about `json.h` and `curl.h` files.
Complete log file is attached.

Also I am getting error for lua5.3:

Package lua5.3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
| Perhaps you should add the directory containing `lua5.3.pc'
| to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
| No package 'lua5.3' found

I have not enabled "lua" in SWUpdate General Configurations.

The /usr/include has both json.h and curl.h files.
[usr/include](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfxR3.png)

I have installed all the libraries mentioned in https://sbabic.github.io/swupdate/swupdate.html#configuration-and-build . Still I am having same issues.

P.S: The initial build with default config(no suricatta) had no issues. I am on Ubuntu 20.04 machine.  I am using **Yocto Project** as build system. I tried some of the solutions from internet but nothing worked for me

Can someone please let me know how to resolve this issues?

[Log file_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ4WN.png)
[Log file_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxonW.png)

Comment: It does not complain about json.h and curl.h! It complains about missing <json-c/json.h> and <curl/curl.h>. Neither json-c nor curl directories are in /usr/include. Do not download that files and copy them to /usr/include. Use Ubuntu package manager.

Comment: You do not need swupdate from sources. You may install it from Ubuntu package manager: libswupdate-dev

Comment: Hi, I have installed both files from apt-get install and in the above screenshot you can see json-c folder also. But I created curl folder and included curl related files. But even then I am getting same issue.

Installing libswupdate-dev? Is this the recommended way? I could not find about this in their documentation?

Comment: P.S:  I am using Yocto Project as build system.